# Angularjs ng-repeat filter all data not just the filtered results

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Hi I'm new in angularjs i just have question to ask.

this is my ng-repeat code.

```
<ul ng-repeat="todo in filteredData | filter:search">
```

And it seems that this code will only filter the filteredData not the alldata itself.

filteredData  is always equal to 10 becuase i'am using a pagination in angularjs.

Now my question is there a way that i can filter alldata not just the filteredData?
i tried

```
<tr ng-repeat="todo in filteredData | filter:alldata:search">
```

but is dosen't work.

Thanks

Comment: A filter is applied to a variable before '|'. So `filteredData` will be filtered. How do you get `filteredData`?

Comment: How does filteredData get created?  That is where you need to appy the search filter.  The `filter` filter just filters whatever the source is, so you would need to do `todo in alldata | filter:search`, then apply the pagination.

Comment: @GoshaFighten i get the filteredData by dividing the allData/numPerPage.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat yeah but if i use allData it will display all and pagination won't work already

Comment: Think of it this way...  If you go to a fruit stand and ask for ten apples and they give you 6 green and 4 red apples, then you take only the green apples you will only have 6 apples.  You want to first ask for green apples, then take 10 of those.  The filter needs to happen before your pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create pagination as a filter.
Then your code will be

```
<tr ng-repeat="todo in alldata | filter:search | pagination:pageNum:perPage">
```

Pagination filter:

```
module.filter('pagination', function(){
  return function(array, page, perPage){
    return array.slice(page * perPage, (page+1) * perPage);
  }
});
```

Full working codepen here: http://codepen.io/SimeonC/pen/gbpqNM?editors=101 (Excuse the jade and coffeescript - the eye above the editor shows you the compiled HTML/JS)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this let assume your full data list is stored in

`$scope.allData`

then you can uses in your `<li>`

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in filterdData = (allData | filter:search)"> </li>
```